# How to get lateral position in flow

Tags: flow-project

I want to get the position of cars in flow.
I know using both `self.k.vehicle.get_position` and `self.k.vehicle.get_x_by_id` can get longitudinal position.

I checked methods in `flow/core/kernel/vehicle/traci.py`,there are `get_edge` `get_lane` `get_headway`, but it seems like there is no method to return the lateral position or the relative lateral distance between cars.

I wonder how can I get lateral position in flow.

If anyone get any idea of this, please tell me!

Thank you and happy new year!

Comment: Hi Elizabeth and happy new year! We're migrating these questions to the flow Slack channel; would you mind asking it there? Link here: https://join.slack.com/t/flow-users/shared_invite/enQtODQ0NDYxMTQyNDY2LTY1ZDVjZTljM2U0ODIxNTY5NTQ2MmUxMzYzNzc5NzU4ZTlmNGI2ZjFmNGU4YjVhNzE3NjcwZTBjNzIxYTg5ZmY

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for reminding me! I've posted the question on Slack.